# Azure DevOps - The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlServerlessDatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid

Tags: azure-devops, azure-synapse, sqlpackage

I have an Azure VMSS scale set running VMs with the below image...

```
source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftVisualStudio"      
    offer     = "visualstudio2022"           
    sku       = "vs-2022-comm-latest-ws2022" 
    version   = "latest"
  }
```

There is a custom Power-Shell script that runs each time a VM is started.

The PowerShell script downloads chocolatey and installs the below software and sets the PATH environment variable adding a reference to where 'sqlpackage.exe' is installed on the VM... "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin" (I have logged on to the VM and checked this is correct)

```
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation

choco install dotnet -y     
choco install sqlpackage -y 
choco install dacfx-18 -y   

#choco install sql2017-dacframework --version 14.0.3757.2 -y

$p = $env:PATH
if (!($p.Contains("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin"))) { 
  
  Write-Host "`n****************** Debug: Appending to Start (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin) to Env:PATH"  
  #$env:PATH = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin;$p"

  $Path = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin"
 
  $Path = $Path + [IO.Path]::PathSeparator + [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "Machine") 
  
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable( "Path", $Path, "Machine" )


}
else
{
    Write-Host "`n****************** Debug: NOT Appending (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin) to Env:PATH"  
}

$p = "'/Directory:c:\agentdevops1 /Token:$pat_token /Pool:selfhosted-vmss-windows-lds-$env /Url:$url'"
Write-Host "Param $p"

Write-Host "`n****************** Debug Install: azure-pipelines-agent"
choco install azure-pipelines-agent --force --params "$p"
```

The VMs in the VMSS act as self-hosted VMS each with their own 'azure devOps agent' linking to Azure Build and Release pipelines.

The Azure Build and Release pipelines are carrying out DAC-PAC tasks.The Az Service-Principal that is linked to the 'pipeline' has database 'owner' permisisons.

Where the DAC-PAC task is run against an 'Azure SQL Database' it completes successfully.

Where the DAC-PAC Publish task is run against an 'Azure Synapse Database' it FAILS with the below error.

```
2023-11-26T09:39:21.4095525Z "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"C:\agentdevops1\_work\r1\a\_SQL\DACPAC-Registrar\Registrar.dacpac" /TargetServerName:""isl-XXX-XXX-sqlsrv01.database.windows.net"" /TargetDatabaseName:"Registrar" /AccessToken:"********" /v:AzureDataLakeStorage="islXXXXXXXdatalakesa"
2023-11-26T09:39:21.6055840Z Publishing to database 'Registrar' on server 'isl-XXX-XXX-sqlsrv01.database.windows.net'.
2023-11-26T09:39:22.0702915Z Initializing deployment (Start)
2023-11-26T09:39:22.3009340Z Initializing deployment (Failed)
2023-11-26T09:39:22.4995063Z ##[error]*** Could not deploy package.
2023-11-26T09:39:22.5079532Z ##[error]Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlServerlessDatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
2023-11-26T09:39:22.5478215Z ##[error]The Azure SQL DACPAC task failed. SqlPackage.exe exited with code 1.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-
2023-11-26T09:39:22.5776187Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure SQL DacpacTask: Registrar
```

The below choco commands install the 'sqlpackage' and Dac-Framework on the VM before any operations are executed by the devOps pipeline. Note: 'sqlpackage.exe' is the main software required.

```
choco install dotnet -y     
 choco install sqlpackage -y 
 choco install dacfx-18 -y
```

The error maybe that the wrong version of one of the above is being installed.

```
"Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlServerlessDatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid."
```

**Any thoughts or suggestions on how to fix? (NB: I can't use Windows Hosted VMs in the Azure devOps pipelines)**

Comment: I am now reading through this reported issue...

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ssdt-doesnt-support-openrowset-provider-syntax/1470331

Comment: Hi, can you login to the agent and run [SqlPackage Publish command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver16) manually to see if the same error will happen? In this way we can narrow down the issue and know if the issue is related to the Azure DevOps task or the sqlpackage.exe itself.

Comment: When I switch the pipliene to run on a "Azure hosted VM agent" the pipeline completes successfully. NB: I can't use a this method for my 'test' and 'prod' as resources are behind private-end-points.

Comment: When I run "SqlPackage /DiagnosticsFile:sqlpackage_logging /at:"$AccessToken" /Action:Publish...." from the Azure self-hosted VM I see the same error message reported when running via the Az devOps pipeline....
"Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlServerlessDatabaseSchemaProvider is not 
valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service."

Comment: Maybe an Az devOPs agent issue.

Comment: Microsoft.Data.Tools.Diagnostics.Tracer Verbose: 1 : 2023-11-29T08:35:14 : Entering ExtensionTypeLoader.LoadTypes().
Microsoft.Data.Tools.Diagnostics.Tracer Error: 19 : 2023-11-29T08:35:15 : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServicesException: Could not deploy package. ---> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.DeploymentFailedException: Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlServerlessDatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.

Comment: at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Extensibility.ExtensionTypeLoader.InstantiateDatabaseSchemaProvider(String databaseSchemaProviderType)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Extensibility.ExtensionManager.UpdateExtensions()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Extensibility.ExtensionManager..ctor(String databaseSchemaProviderType)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Extensibility.ExtensionManager.GetExtensionManager(String dsp)

Comment: Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.CreateExtensionManagerFromModel(SqlPackage package)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.CreateExtensionManagerFromModel(SqlPackage package)
Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentEndpointPackage.OnInit(ErrorManager errors, String targetDBName)
Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment..ctor(SqlDeploymentConstructor constructor)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentConstructor.ConstructServiceImplementation()

Comment: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.CreatePackageToDatabaseDeployment(SqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory, IPackageSource packageSource, String targetDatabaseName, DacDeployOptions options, ErrorManager errorManager)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<>c__DisplayClass5.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__1()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.OperationLogger.Capture(Action action)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__0(Object operation, CancellationToken token)

Comment: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Operation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.ReportMessageOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)

Comment: Just compared OS Version, the Azure hosted agents run on...
2023-11-29T08:30:40.9841785Z ##[group]Operating System
2023-11-29T08:30:40.9841980Z Microsoft Windows Server 2022
2023-11-29T08:30:40.9842087Z 10.0.20348

Comment: Agents are slightly different:

Self-Hosted agents = Current agent version: '3.230.0' /

Azure hsoted agents version= Current agent version: '3.230.2'

Comment: I tried to install SqlPackage from choco, the SqlPackage version form choco is [SqlPackage 161.8089.0](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/sqlpackage). Can you try to use `dotnet tool install -g microsoft.sqlpackage` to download the latest 162.1.167.1 version?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me. In my custom Powershell script that runs when a VM from the VMSS is started...

## use evergreen or specific dacfx msi link below

```
    wget -O DacFramework.msi "https://aka.ms/dacfx-msi"
    msiexec.exe /i "DacFramework.msi" /qn
```

Also added the below location to the PATH env. variable via the Powershell script...

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin"